# Azure Logic Apps - HTTP+XML Service

Tags: xml, post, logic, azure-logic-apps

I was wondering if someone could please assist as I am new to Logic Apps.

Our ERP System has a HTTP+XML rest service for sending XML files to integrate with.

I am having trouble setting up the HTTP connector within Logic Apps to POST the required XML Data it also requires authentication with username and password.

Can someone please provide an example of how this achieved?

Comment: Could you give an example of `HTTP` request? Screenshot or other way of explanation.

Comment: HTTP Request: Connection URL - Request Body is required XSD file but also need supply HTTPS Username and Password in order for it to connect. Problems I have Azure Logic Apps is mainly JSON based and ERP requires XML.

Comment: Could you please give us a screenshot of your logic app?

Comment: Does [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGcqn.png) can solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Frank, Apologies for not getting back to you regarding unfortunately it did not resolve my issue I think it maybe as my coding is very limited. I have however used postman successfully and found it to assist.